# Laravel 5 - I can't see any view

Tags: php, laravel-5

I want to try out Laravel 5. I actually know something about L4. I know a stable release of L5 is not already lunched. But I have tried twice to install it and, when I change anything in the view, something is broken and, from this moment, I can't see anything. The app can't access to the views... I have just tried to change 'Laravel 5' to 'Laravel 7', just to play with the view, and now I can't display any `View`.

I'm not able to get my templates, and I only can display text directly from my 'controllers'. Like so:

```
public function index()
{
    return 'hello';
}
```

Any idea what may be wrong?

**EDIT**

My project schedule folder:

```
-project
--app
--bootstrap
--public
--resources
---(...)
---templates
----welcome.blade.php
--storage
--tests
--vendor
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have managed to install Laravel 5 then fresh installation should work.

Probably something blows up and traces of it must be seen in the server error_log or in the laravel log in storage/logs.

It could be file permission issue or missing dependency like mcrypt.